# Questions about GemStone/S

Tags: smalltalk, object-oriented-database, gemstone

I'm having a hard time understanding the big picture of GemStone for Smalltalk. I am aware of GLASS as an application server using Linux, Seaside and Apache. But I want to know if it is an usable environment for non-Seaside applications.

I'm also having trouble to finding some basic questions:

It is not clear to me if GLASS or GemStone/S is independent of the VM used. For example if I'm using a VM which supports black threads, does that mean that the GemStone/S will work transparently?

For what I've seen also it is not useful for 3D applications. For example, if my application developed in Pharo or VisualWorks uses OpenGL, may I consider GemStone/S for scaling up?

I've read that you may have objects in VisualWorks and objects in GemStone/S, but this confuses me a lot. How do I know if the object I've just created it is already persisted or in "client" side? In which case I need GemBuilder?

Comment: [Stephan Eggermont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35306) posted this in an Answer earlier: James Foster posted an excellent detailed overview of the implementation on YouTube. The series starts at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0z5TddqyQI

Answer (score 3):

To get an understanding of the big picture of Gemstone/S, you can read [Gemstone 101](http://gemstonesoup.wordpress.com/gemstone-101/).

Many of your questions should be answered and some of them are also not applicable. For example, Gemstone/S is a complete Smalltalk implementation with its own VM. It also does not have a visual interface like Pharo, Squeak or Visualworks.

Comment: I am asking here precisely because I didn't found any useful answer (for me) in Gemstone 101. Maybe my questions are *that* hard?

Comment: Your questions are too generic. How can we answer something like 'What happens if I do not need Seaside?' or 'How do I know if I need GemBuilder'? I answered two of your basic questions above, but I think you might be better of asking more specific questions if you want someone to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: You need to split the question into several ones.

For example: 
*Is GLASS or GemStone/S  independent of the VM used?*

No, as far as I understand the question. GemStone needs its own VM. You cannot run GemStone on a VM of another Smalltalk.